# Unable to suppress Excel Display Alerts

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to suppress the message which pops up on deletion of sheet in the embedded excel of a PPT chart, using this code snippet:

**POP-UP MESSAGE**

[image]

**CODE-SNIPPET:**

```
Sub MainSub()

     ' Some code here
      ' reference to excel has been added
       If SelShape.HasChart = True Then
        Dim SelChart As PowerPoint.Chart
        Set SelChart = SelShape.Chart
        Dim Selchtdat As PowerPoint.ChartData
        Set Selchtdat = SelChart.ChartData
           On Error Resume Next
             Selchtdat.Activate
           On Error GoTo 0
        Dim EmbdExcel As Excel.Workbook
        Set EmbdExcel = Selchtdat.Workbook
        Call FilterRequiredData (EmbdExcel, "Data")
  End If

' Some code here

End Sub
```

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
  Private Sub FilterRequiredData(ChrtWbk As Excel.Workbook, stname As String)

            ChrtWbk .Activate
            On Error Resume Next
              Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
              ChrtWbk.Sheets("TempSheet").Delete
              Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            On Error GoTo 0
            ChrtWbk.Sheets.Add(After:=ChrtWbk.Sheets(ChrtWbk.Sheets.count)).Name = "TempSheet"
            
           'Some other code 
  End Sub
```

This code works perfectly in the native Excel VBA environment, but when invoked in PPT VBA Environment, it doesn't suppress the message. Can anybody tell me why this doesn't work ? Are there any other ways to tackle this ?

Comment: How is `ChrtWbk` defined? And did you set a variable to `Excel.Application` object? You will need to show more code showing how you defined those variables.

Comment: Firstly, no need of `On error resume next`. Then, what `Excel` is in your code context? If it is the Excel session object, your code must work. As @Raymond Wu suggested, you should edit your question and show us how involved variables have been declared and Set.

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, I have updated my question. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: @RaymondWu Hi, I have set reference to excel library and ChrtWbk is defined as Excel.Workbook

Comment: Then, if you extract the workbook object from the chart, please try `ChrtWbk.Parent.Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, of course, followed by `True`. You should extract the Excel object form the involved workbook... If it does not work, please try: `ChrtWbk.Parent.DisplayAlerts = False`...

Comment: As FaneDuru said, you need to explicitly tell VBA which `Excel.Application` object are you referring to. Also - I believe `ChrtWbk .Activate` is unnecessary unless you want to see your screen popping back and forth for no reason. @Charlie

Comment: Okay, i will try those and let you know.

Comment: And, of course, as  @Raymond Wu remarked, ` ChrtWbk .Activate` is useless. Anyhow, it is a typo in it (a space before `.Actrivate`)...

Comment: Thank you so much guys.  This line worked .ChrtWbk.Parent.Application.DisplayAlerts = False.

Comment: Please, try the next one, too (`ChrtWbk.Parent.DisplayAlerts = False`. It may work, too. Just for the sake of testing. I cannot test it right now...

Comment: ChrtWbk.Parent.DisplayAlerts = False.  Even this works as well. Thanks again. On similar note, how can i suppress the save prompts if a excel workbook is opened from ppt. If i use the same idea, won't it throw an error at the line where display alerts is set back to true, as the workbook is closed and hence object is released.

Comment: @Charlie Try passing `True` to the `SaveChanges` argument when closing the workbook [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close)

Comment: I did try that. From the PPT environment setting the SaveChanges arg to either True/false doesn't suppress the prompt. However in this case enclosing the close statement within Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts =True/False is working. What exactly is the EXCEL in Excel.Application doing i wonder .

Comment: Use the same way, please. Ups. You were faster and already tried it... :)

Comment: If I use the same idea, it throws an error at the line where display alerts is set back to true, probably because in this case the workbook is being closed, hence object is released in the previous line. This is what I tried:  <br/> 
     *WPSWorkbook.Parent.DisplayAlerts = False  <br/>
     WPSWorkbook.Close , True  <br/>
    WPSWorkbook.Parent.DisplayAlerts = False  'Throws error here*

Comment: Application is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object))...

Comment: No any object (workbook) to be used for extracting the `Application` object... In order to not let Excel application without sending alerts, you should declare a new variable: `Dim ExApp as Object`, followed by `Set ExAp = WPSWorkbook.Parent`. Then, simple use it as:  `ExAp.DisplayAlerts = False`, followed by `ExAp.DisplayAlerts = True` (no error this time, the object existing already...).

Comment: Forgive the mess that is my previous comment. I am trying to format it... :D. Thanks for the quick reply. Trying that now

Comment: Working like charm. Thanks so much. If only I could think like you guys.